Can't receive push notif in capacitorjs using FCM
I creating app using CapacitorJS and Svelte with php Backend, my problem is I fail to implement push notification while app is backgrounded (or killed)
here my Android manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />



</manifest>


here my custom java class extending firebaseCloudMessaging
package com.appapp.omi;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.capacitorjs.plugins.pushnotifications.PushNotificationsPlugin;
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginHandle;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import com.getcapacitor.Bridge;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginManager;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "PushNotificationService";
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "default_channel";

   

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = "Default Title";
        String body = "Default Body";

        JSObject dataObj = new JSObject();

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        } else if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            // Handle custom data payload
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        }

        if (MainActivity.bridge != null) {
            PluginHandle pushPluginHandle = MainActivity.bridge.getPlugin("PushNotifications");
            if (pushPluginHandle != null) {
                PushNotificationsPlugin pushPlugin = (PushNotificationsPlugin) pushPluginHandle.getInstance();
                pushPlugin.fireNotification(remoteMessage);
            }
//            MainActivity.bridge.triggerJSEvent("pushNotificationReceived", jsonString);
            // MainActivity.bridge.triggerWindowJSEvent("pushNotificationReceived", data.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("MyFirebaseService", "Bridge not initialized");
        }
        // Show notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // Replace with your app's notification icon
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
    
}

here my implementation pushnotif in capacitorjs
export async function registerPushNotifications() {
  try {

    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((status) => {
      console.log({status})
      if (status.receive === 'granted') {
        PushNotifications.addListener(
          "pushNotificationReceived",
          (notification) => {
            console.log()
            // console.log({notification: JSON.parse(notification)});
            addGNotif(notification);
          },
        );

        // Listener for errors
        PushNotifications.addListener("registrationError", (error) => {
          console.error("Push registration error:", error);
        });

        PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', (action) => {
          console.log(action)
          alert("clicked")
        });

        FCM.getToken()
          .then((r) => {
            saveToken(r.token);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }
    })



  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Push notification setup failed:', error);
  }
}


here my backend php

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;


function appapp_sendPushNotification($registrationTokens, $title, $body, $data = []) {
    // Initialize Firebase
    $factory = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount(ABSPATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'wp-content'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'firebase-service-account.json'); // Optional if using Realtime Database

    $messaging = $factory->createMessaging();

    
    
     $message = CloudMessage::new()
         ->withData($data)
        ->withTarget('token', $registrationTokens)->withHighestPossiblePriority()->withAndroidConfig(array('priority' => 'high'));

    try {
        $response = $messaging->send($message);
        // $response = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, $registrationTokens);
        error_log(json_encode($response));
        return $response;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());

        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}


my capacitor version is v.6
"@capacitor/android": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.1.2",
    "@capacitor/inappbrowser": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.3",
    "@capacitor/local-notifications": "^6.1.1",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^6.0.2",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^6.0.3",


my capacitor config
{
  "appId": "com.appapp.omi",
  "appName": "OMI App",
  "webDir": "dist/client",
  "allowNavigation": ["wa.me", "api.whatsapp.com", "orbitalmedika.co.id"],
  "plugins": {
    "PushNotifications": {
      "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
    },
    "Keyboard": {
      "resize": "none"
    }
  }
}


while app in foreground, notification is received but not while in background
